# CGFloat has weird default value

Tags: ios, objective-c

I just got confronted with very weird bug, which happened probably due to lack of my knowledge on Objective C data types.
If I do this:

```
CGFloat newY;
NSLog(@"newY is %f", newY);
```

Log returns **0.0**, although I would expect nil, but that's not the real problem. If I now export this app to iOS .ipa and install the app from there the newY gets automatically initialized to **185.000**.
Where does this value come from and why it is different when the app is installed from .ipa and not directly from XCode?

I would really appreciate any insight on what's happening, it doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: In C you need to initialize local variables. The value you're seeing is a garbage value, depending on various factors. Normally, compilers warn about such things. Did you ignore a warning here?

Comment: You need to initialize variable `newY`. else it will give you garbage value not 0.0.

Comment: Yes I figured out that i have to initialize local variable. I just couldn't understand why different values were assigned. It makes more sense now. I think I didn't get any compiler warning as I was incrementing the variable in foreach loop newY = newY + 1.0f; Thanks a lot for your insights.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

newY is not initialized to zero, it is whatever happens to be on the stack (which is where newY is stored) at the time. This may be different on different platforms but may also change between executions.

You are most likely getting a warning telling you that it is unsafe to use newY before initializing it yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. There were actually no warnings, I would most certainly look into it if I got any warnings.

Comment: If your initial use of newY is `newY = newY + 1.0f`, the compiler may not catch that. Do you get a warning if your first use is `other = newY + 1.0f`?

Comment: Yes I get a warning when using `other = newY + 1.0f`, so this is the reason why I didn't get the warning before. I still don't understand what's the difference when running the app through XCode and standalone. It's the same physical device, same OS, same app. Even with detached debugger, the app still works as expected when installed from XCode. I understand that this happens due to my error, but it would be nice to know what makes this difference in the background.

Comment: The point is that the memory is not initialized at all. Getting the same value over and over again is a fragile situation, you're much more likely to get different values when running the app under different conditions.

Answer (score 1):

CGFloat is not a pointer, so it can't be assign nil.

This is an automatic variable, so it is given a place in memory, and it takes the value which is already stored as you don't initialize it. The value is undefined, so you should initialize it.

Comment: CGFloat is not a structure it is `typedef` to `float` or `double` depenging on platform.

Comment: @MaxK. Totally right, I was thinking about CGRect, It's edited.